# Por que este codigo me muestra una matriz de puros ceros?

Tags: bucles, matriz, pseint, pseudocódigo, sl

Para este algoritmo estoy utilizando **SLE** un **IDE** para el lenguaje **SL**, tambien puedo utilizar **PSeInt**. Tengo un problema con el siguiente algoritmo y es que me muestra puros ceros y estoy utilizando un ciclo **Repetir...Hasta** y estoy inicializando mi matriz para mostrar los valores random que necesito. Pero no me muestra los valores al final.

Incluso yo estoy incrementando mi iteracion para la matriz. No entiendo porque el ciclo **Repetir...Hasta** no funciona bien para matrices.

```
    const 
    N = 5
var 
    i, j, datobuscar : numerico
    m : vector [N, N] numerico 
inicio 
    cls()

    i = 1
    
    repetir
     
     repetir
     m[i, j] = random(100)
     j = j + 1
     hasta (j <= N)
     i = i + 1
     
    hasta (i <= N)

    imprimir ("\n Matriz desordenado: ")
    imprimir ("\n")
    desde i = 1 hasta N
    {
     desde j = 1 hasta N
     {
      imprimir (" ", m[i, j])
        imprimir ("")
     }
     imprimir ("\n")
    }
    
    imprimir ("\n Introduzca el valor a buscar: ")
    imprimir ('\n ')
    leer(datobuscar)
fin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varios problemas:

1. Asignación a la matriz, en lugar de `m[N, N] = random(100)` debería ser `m[i, j] = random(100)`. Ya que en el primer caso, siempre estás asignando el valor a la última posición de la matriz.
2. La condición de los ciclos **repetir**, debe ser `(i>N)` y `(j>N)`. La condición de entrada al ciclo sólo se cumple más que una vez, y no se llenan las posiciones restantes . Esto provoca que la matriz tenga el valor por default para las demás posiciones (0).
3. Falta inicializar la variable j antes de la entrada a cada ciclo anidado.
   El código siguiente debería funcionar:

   ```
    const 
       N = 3
    var 
       i, j, datobuscar : numerico
       m : vector [N, N] numerico 
   inicio 
     cls()

     i = 1
     repetir
       j = 1
       repetir
          m[i, j] = random(100)
          j = j + 1
       hasta (j > N)
       i = i + 1
     hasta (i > N)

     imprimir ("\n Matriz desordenado: ")
     imprimir ("\n")
     desde i = 1 hasta N
     {
        desde j = 1 hasta N
        {
           imprimir (" ", m[i, j])
           imprimir ("")
        }
        imprimir ("\n")
      }
    imprimir ("\n Introduzca el valor a buscar: ")
    imprimir ('\n ')
    leer(datobuscar)
   fin
   ```

Comment: Señor @Javier Resendiz. cambie esa parte. Pero me sigue dando el mismo problema esta vez no es en la ultima posicion. ahora es en la primera posicion de la matriz. Edite el codigo de mi respuesta y corregi m[N, N] = random(100).

Comment: Agregué a la respuesta datos adicionales del porqué no funciona correctamente. Con eso ya no debes tener problema.

Comment: Señor @JavierResendiz en el ciclo **Repetir** ¿por que `(i > N)` y `(j > N)` tienen que ser mayores a **N**?